# angular material icons renders first before the interpolation

Tags: material-ui, angular-material, frontend, material-icons

I'm doing an angular project using angular material, while im using mat-icons it keeps coming before the interpolation even though i coded it after the interpolation [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSttU.png)

i tried typing anything before of after the icon and the icon comes first no matter what

Sort by {{sort}}
expand_more

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it documented anywhere in the official docs for some reason (in neither `mat-button` or `mat-icon` parts at least).
Lukcily, it's at least documented in the migration guide [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#button).

What you need to do since v15 is to add iconPositionEnd directive to the `mat-icon` inside the `mat-button`, e.g.

```
<button mat-button>
  Icon after text
  <mat-icon iconPositionEnd>favorite</mat-icon>
</button>
```

EDIT: There already is a git issue about this feature not being documented [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26259).